# Need help re-architecting and optimizing a large solr index

Tags: java, solr, lucene, indexing

I have a working Solr index, but I need help re-architecting it to make it smaller, faster, less resource intensive.

**Current:**

- One index holds data for past 10 years.
- Daily, 5k new text files are indexed
- The index size is approx. 40 GB annually so 400GB for 10 yrs combined.

**Requirements:**

- Ability to nightly update index with new files
- Ability to rebuild index from src files - hopefully speed it up.
- Ability to keep current large number of facet fields (30 or so).
- Ability to keep "highlight" - so text from extracted docs can be displayed.

**Questions:**

1. When rebuilding the index from scratch, what are the tradeoffs (build time, memory requirement, processing requirement) and when to issue "commit" and "optimize"?:

   - building one single 10 year index (hard to distributed during build time)
   - building 1 index per year - and then merging them
   - building 1 index per either month, week or day, and then merging them together
2. How to merge (what are the tradeoffs):

   - Use cmd line lucene index merge tool, or web instance of solr, or JAVA API?
   - How much more temporary disk space is needed for merge time (besides source indexes + final index size)
   - Are there any memory requirements for merge?
   - Is it better to merge two at a time or merge all at the same time?
   - is there any way to have lucene cmd line index merge tool to output progress?
3. How to run the index:

   - One large index
   - Sharded index - multi core - with each year in its own core.
4. How to apply daily updates:

   - apply to main index
   - create new daily core as new shard and not merge.
   - create new daily core and merge daily core with the full index
5. What are the memory, disk and CPU considerations? What would you guess a single machine requirement would be (for dev/prototype environment, not for internet scale production)?
6. I need to keep highlighting. Is there way to either not store the text field, or to shrink?? doc somewhat to reduce the size of final index without removing ability to highlight in search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to merge (what are the tradeoffs)

Why don't you consider 'Sharding'? In this case, you won't have to merge them. You can keep keep your data sharded per 2-year period or whatever period you decide. Queries will be faster as well, as it will use distributed search functionality.

Look at:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud

Comment: Thanks. I needed to run on single machine. While I was aware of it, I don't know how memory/CPU requirements change for same amount of data split across shards. I will likely try multi-core sharding with one index that is built 1-time and 1 index that is updated daily.